# mvc5 ajax not refreshing Partial View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a View which contains a textbox, a button and a virtual book in a partial view. After Pressing the button, the text from the textbox is placed on the first page of the book and then the book (the partial view) should be refreshed.

With the Ajax I can call the method PlaceText (which place a text on the first page/image of the book) but it doesn't refresh the partial view _Book.

I tried

```
$("#services").load("_Book");
```

and

```
$("#services").load("PlaceText");
```

and many more things after reading these solutions for a similar problem, but nothing seems to work. The allert("ok") appears, but the partialView doesn't refresh

```
                        <script type ="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#myLink").click(function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    var textboxvalue = $('input[name=your-name]').val();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        data: { name: textboxvalue },
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: '@Url.Action("PlaceText", "Home")',
                                        success: function (result) {

                                                $("#services").html("_Book");
                                                alert("ok");
                                        }

                                    });
                                });
                            });

                        </script>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Mehet", "PlaceText", null, new { id = "myLink" })
```

This is my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult PlaceText(string name)
    {

        PointF firstLocation = new PointF(700f, 80f);

        string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/images/demo1/elolap3.jpg");
        string imageFilePath2 = Server.MapPath(@"~/images/demo1/elolap1.jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using (Font arialFont = new Font("Bigfish", 40))
            {
                graphics.DrawString(name, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
            }
        }

        bitmap.Save(imageFilePath2);//save the image file
        return PartialView("_Book", db.imageModel.ToList());
    }
```

This is my view (Index):

```
    <section id="services" class="services service-section">
        @Html.Partial("_Book");
    </section>
```

My partial view:

```
<div class="Heidelberg-Book with-Spreads" id="Heidelberg-example-1">

@foreach (var image in Model)
{
    <div class="Heidelberg-Spread">
        <img src="@Url.Content(image.FilePath)" />
    </div>
}

</div>
```

Comment: `$("#services").html(result);`

Comment: I forgot to mention, this was the first thing I tried... Same problem

Comment: What problem? It will work fine (i.e replace the contents of your `<section id="services" .. />` with the partial returned by `PlaceText()` method). Although its unclear what that method is actually doing and why you pass a value for `name` when its never even used (it appears it would always return exactly the same partial)

Comment: That 'name' is used at 'graphics.DrawString'. That word is placed on the first image. I need the model to be returned (the images from database). When I ran the project the Index shows up fine, I can see the book (partialView) generated from the database but after I press the button and the new image replace the first page of the book (this works) my book does not change.

Comment: But you never saving a `Book` (just an image file)

Comment: Yes, I'm saving only an image file (overwrite the first image) and then I want to display all images from the database in my `book` without reloading the page. How can it be done? If I try with `$("#services").html(result);` my book looses the animation (javascript) (I can't shuffle, it only displays the **unmodified** first image. Normally when I click on an image it turns a page). So something gets replaced but the pages of the book are the same.